How can I use a template from a dependency?
I have a Quarkus module that defines an abstract REST class. It contains Qute templates which should be injected. Then I have my application which uses the module as dependency and implements a REST service which extends the abstract REST class.
If I use a template directly in my application (in the REST service), it works. But if I want to use a template in my dependent Maven module, I always get an error, because the template is not found.
So how can I use Qute within a dependency?
Here's some more information about the structure: I have src/main/resources/templates/health_state.html in my module.
In the abstract base class, I use
  @Inject
  @Location("health_state.html")
  Template healthState;

At startup time, I get this error:
No template found for path [health_state.html] defined at foobar.quarkus.healthcheck.AbstractHealthCheckResource#healthState
    - available templates: []
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanDeployment.processErrors(BeanDeployment.java:1516)
    at io.quarkus.arc.processor.BeanProcessor.processValidationErrors(BeanProcessor.java:180)
    at io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor.generateResources(ArcProcessor.java:518)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)


Can show the error you are getting and example of the module structure you are using?

@geoand I added more information. Thanks for any help!

Or is this the solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66428533/quarkus-qute-template-location-from-another-maven-module

Let's see what @martin-kouba thinks

Ok, I'll be away for a while and check Stackoverflow in mid-January.

It's really weird. I tried to add a TemplateLocator :
@Locate(".*")
public class HealthCheckTemplateLocator implements TemplateLocator {

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HealthCheckTemplateLocator.class);

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  @Override
  public Optional<TemplateLocation> locate(final String id) {
    LOG.infof("Locating template %s", id);
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}

If I use this in the module, it doesn't work. If I use it in the application, everything suddenly works. But I don't see anything in the log... strange!

Have you made your external module discoverable for Quarkus ? If not try this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75046455/2979325
If this also doesn’t work, then a dirty solution might be to unpack your templates  into the current project build folder by using the following maven plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246960/2979325
